# Textarea doesn't work with touch on iPad/Android tablet

Tags: php, html, symfony-1.4

I have a textarea created by Symfony 1.4 like this:

```
$this->setWidget('message', new sfWidgetFormTextarea());
```

And when I want to be able to edit it with my tablet, I can't get the keyboard up to write text. Although when I make it as a input field:

```
$this->setWidget('message', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
```

I am able to put in text, but I don't get the functionality of a textarea.

Does anyone know how to fix this or get the input field to behave like a textarea?

Comment: you should really switch to new symfony2?

Comment: @pregmatch I just keep this website maintained and hope to fix this easily instead of rebuilding the site in Symfony2

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML if everything is fine there? Maybe it's some transparent element covering your `textarea`?